# How do you create odd looking grids in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

How do you create odd looking grids in Bootstrap 4? For example,

The leftmost column spans two rows, and to its right two rows each having 3 colums

```
||||||||||||||||
|     |  |  |  |
|     |_ |_ |_ |
|     |  |  |  |
|_____|_ |_ |_ |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Bootstrap's grids, you should think about the layout of the columns instead of the layout of the rows. The layout of the columns is dependent on the height of the content inside of the cells.

To demonstrate a row that spans two columns, I have fixed the height of the rows

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-md-6">
         <div style="height: 400px; background-color: rgb(26, 188, 156);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-6">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(231, 76, 60);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(52, 73, 94);"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(22, 160, 133);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(230, 126, 34);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">
               <div style="height: 200px; background-color: rgb(149, 165, 166);"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```